# How to replace all instances of a comma in MATLAB except for a specific situation

Tags: regex, matlab, replace

I want to replace all occurrences of a comma in a few lines of text.

i.e.

```
"3","0.998652","10.1.3.2","10.1.2.3","TCP","[TCP Port numbers reused] 49153 > 10 [SYN] Seq=4294967295 Win=65535 Len=0"
"4","1.002860","10.1.2.3","10.1.3.2","TCP","10 > 49153 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0"
```

In the above lines, you can see that almost every occurrence of a comma is surrounded by quotations (","). All I want to do is to leave them in, but replace all occurrences of commas that are not surrounded by quotations with a blank space using MATLAB.

This is what I would like out:

```
"3","0.998652","10.1.3.2","10.1.2.3","TCP","[TCP Port numbers reused] 49153 > 10 [SYN] Seq=4294967295 Win=65535 Len=0"
"4","1.002860","10.1.2.3","10.1.3.2","TCP","10 > 49153 [SYN ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0"
```

Note the only difference is that the comma in the [SYN ACK] part is removed.

I've tried many things, but so far the only thing that has worked would be something like this.

```
a= '"4","1.002860","10.1.2.3","10.1.3.2","TCP","10 > 49153 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0"'
str = regexprep(a,'","','1234567890')
str = regexprep(str,',','')
str = regexprep(str,'1234567890','","')
```

Needless to say, this is far from optimal and would appreciate any ideas. Something to be aware of too, some of the functions I tried didn't seem to recognize the quotations (can't remember which off hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexprep` is the way to go, you only have to make sure to replace the comma only (by putting back the flanking parts of the match using the `$1` match placeholders.

```
a= '"4","1.002860","10.1.2.3","10.1.3.2","TCP","10 > 49153 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0"'

%# replace commas that are neither preceded nor followed by commas
regexprep(a,'([^"]),([^"])','$1$2')

ans =

"4","1.002860","10.1.2.3","10.1.3.2","TCP","10 > 49153 [SYN ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=65535 Len=0"
```